# Python 2 not working referer

Tags: python, python-2.7, referer

I want to add a referer while retrieving data from the web but this is not working on my python2 referer `request.add_header('Referer', 'https://www.python.org')`.

My Url.txt content

> https://www.python.org/about/
>   
>   https://stackoverflow.com/questions
>   
>   https://docs.python.org/2.7/

These are my codes

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import re
import urllib2
import threading
import time
import requests

max_thread = 5
urllist = open("Url.txt").readlines()

def url_connect(url):
    try :
        request = urllib2.Request(url)
        request.add_header('Referer', 'https://www.python.org')
        request.add_header('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0')  
        goo = re.findall('<title>(.*?)</title>', urllib2.urlopen(url.replace(' ','')).read())[0]
        print '\n' + goo.decode("utf-8")
        with open('SaveMyDataFile.txt', 'ab') as f:
            f.write(goo + "\n")

    except Exception as Errors:
        pass

for i in urllist:
    i = i.strip()    

    if i.startswith("http"):        

        while threading.activeCount() >= max_thread:
            time.sleep(0.1)

        threading.Thread(target=url_connect, args=(i,)).start()
```

Comment: `except Exception as Errors:
        pass` isn't exactly the best way to know why it's not working...

Comment: I'm confused.  You're importing the `requests` module, but not using it at all in favor of `urllib2`.  We also can't see what your error is.  Can you explain in what way it's not working?

Comment: @Iguananaut                                                                                                                 I just want to edit the codes I specify

    `def url_connect(url):
        try :
     request = urllib2.Request(url)
     request.add_header('Referer', 'https://www.python.org')
     request.add_header('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0')  
     goo = re.findall('<title>(.*?)</title>', urllib2.urlopen(url.replace(' ','')).read())[0]
            print '\n' + goo.decode("utf-8")
            with open('SaveMyDataFile.txt', 'ab') as f:
                f.write(goo + "\n")`

Comment: This is just a copy of some of your code from above.  What I'm asking is what the problem is.  You wrote "this is not working".  How is it not working?    Why do you think setting the `Referer` header has anything to do with it?

Comment: @Iguananaut I want to add `urllist = open(" Url.txt ").Readlines()` referer to every url I read How can I do that?

Comment: Get rid of the `except pass`, rerun the code and add the error traceback to the question. Do not add new details in comments. Instead edit the original question. [ask]

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me the problem is in your call to urlopen. You call it with the url and not with the request.

Answer (score 0):

From https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html#urllib2.urlopen

> Open the URL url, which can be either a string or a `Request` object.

You need to pass `urllib.urlopen()` the `Request` object that you just built--you're currently not doing anything with that.

Comment: Must be like this  `def url_connect(url):
    try :
 request = urllib2.Request(url)
 request.add_header('Referer', 'https://www.python.org')
 request.add_header('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0')  
 goo = re.findall('<title>(.*?)</title>', urllib2.urlopen(request.replace(' ','')).read())[0]`

Comment: You really only need to paste the one line. And yes but remove the `.replace(...)`. What effect do you think that has on a `Request` object?